# Python subprocess module, sub process calls shell script, console cannot print in real time

Tags: python, shell, printing, subprocess

1. test.py code:

   ```
   sub=subprocess.Popen(["sh", "test.sh"])
   sub.wait()
   ```
2. Use bash in test.sh and then call multiple python script files
   However, after the child process is started, the console displays nothing until the child process ends. But, when set -x is added to test.sh, all outputs of the child process will be printed to the console all at once.I still use the following code, the same effect：

   ```
   sub= subprocess.Popen(["sh", "test.sh"], shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE ,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   while sub.poll() == None or sub.poll() != 0:
       print sub.stdout.readline()
       sub.stdout.flush()
       sys.stdout.flush()
   ```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the contents of test.sh script?

Comment: @dopstar sorry, i can't , the test.sh just calls several different python script files.